# Will `hadoop jar` be executed on NameNode or DataNode?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a question when I submit hadoop jar command to run simple jar without any MR code , does hadoop jar command runs the jar on edge node (name node or  master node) or picks data node as executor similar to Oozie? or do I need to use hadoop-streaming jar to run java jar application?

```
hadoop jar /home/bin/myjar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.test.ImpalaJdbcConnectionTest
```

Comment: Can you clarify your second question, about hadoop-streaming?

Comment: Oozie's Java action is just a wrapper around `java jar` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Java program doesn't instantiate `YarnClient`, and that `YarnClient` doesn't create an `Application` in YARN, then it is run as if you simply called `java -jar <your-jar-file>`, i.e. locally on the node where you execute it.

Comment: my java application is non spark or non map reduce application , lets say it a rest api application I know I can simple integrate with spark by running a spark context in main method other than Oozie or Hadoop streaming Jar is there a way running in data node, I am looking at some yarn client approach just bringing in yarn api into java code

Comment: Check this out https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html.

Comment: I will be probaly using this below for getting data from rest api using spark , https://medium.com/ibm-data-science-experience/using-spark-as-a-parallel-processing-framework-for-accessing-rest-based-data-services-cd4c98526784